# Convert hex number to hex value

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code

```
    Dim sSerialNumber = "9082285F"
    Dim iSerial As Integer = ("&H" & sSerialNumber)
    Dim iSerial2 As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(sSerialNumber, 16)
```

But VB.NET does not like this. The IDE tells me at runtime that a stack overflow was detected in the line

```
Dim iSerial As Integer = ("&H" & sSerialNumber)
```

Does anybody see why and knows how to do that properly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read your error, it stated that you had an exception of System.OverflowException. Try changing your type to Long instead of Integer.

Small Console program to demonstrate.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim sSerialNumber = "9082285F"
    Dim iSerial As Long = ("&H" & sSerialNumber)
    Dim iSerial2 As Long = Convert.ToInt64(sSerialNumber, 16)
    Console.WriteLine(sSerialNumber)
    Console.WriteLine(iSerial)
    Console.WriteLine(Hex(iSerial))
    Console.WriteLine(iSerial2)
    Console.WriteLine(Hex(iSerial2))
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Mark, is there a way to tell Convert.ToInt32 that my string is a hex value? Perhaps my argument is a value where it is unknown if it is a hex value or a long or int.

Comment: Your string is to big to fit into an Int32 try an Int64, What exactly is it that you are trying to do? your iSerial is actually the representation of your Hexadecimal number.

Comment: I only use Convert.ToInt32 in this special case where I read the partition serial of disk, but I thought that I could somehow tell the function that my function is indeed a hex value and not something else.

Comment: You were on the right track, your main problem was that your hexadecimal number was to big, I updated my example to show that the number converts both ways.